# javascript: !( booleanCondition() ) vs ( booleanCondition() == false )

Tags: javascript, extjs4, operators, conditional-statements

The title says it all, 
but let's say I have a hasAccess() function returning true or false

I use it in a ExtJS 4 toolbar button config like this :

```
{
  id:      'btnEditMyStuff',
  ref:     'edit_my_stuff',
  xtype:   'button',
  text:    'Edit',
  hidden:  !( MyUser.hasAccessTo('EditMystuff') )            
}
```

Even if this expression gets correctly evaluated to false when tested in Firebug,
my button won't show up.

But with this :

```
{
  id:      'btnEditMyStuff',
  ref:     'edit_my_stuff',
  xtype:   'button',
  text:    'Edit',
  hidden:  ( MyUser.hasAccessTo('EditMystuff') == false )            
}
```

the button is correctly displayed.

The question is : **what is the difference ?**

What mysterious comparison operators/function evaluation precedence am I overlooking here ?

I want to go to bed less dumb than yesterday.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

```
 hidden:  !( MyUser.hasAccessTo('EditMystuff') )  // does not work
 hidden:  (!MyUser.hasAccessTo('EditMystuff') )   // works
```

but still I crave to fully understand.

Comment: +1 for *I want to go to bed less dumb than yesterday* :-)

Comment: BTW, I can't spot a difference since you are using `==`. Would have been a clear difference had you used `===`.

Comment: The `!` is simple boolean conversion. The `==` uses a complex algorithm using type coercion in order to establish equality *(when the types don't match).

Comment: @squint - But how does that cause a difference to what the condition *returns* `!x` and `x==false` are bound to be the same.

Comment: @techfoobar: Not sure what you mean. Yes, they're presumably operating on the same value, but as I said, one does a simple boolean conversion of the value, while the other isn't so simple. For example, `![]; // false` but `[] == false; // true`

Comment: @techfoobar: If you're talking about the button not showing up when one expression result provides `false`, but showing up when the other expression result provides `false`, well, that's just simply not factual. If that's what OP is claiming, then OP is mistaken.

Comment: @squint - Thank you for the `[] == false` example. That cleared certain things for me. :)

Comment: Though i got your point regarding the difference between the two. In this case, as you said, i can't see why it would behave differently.

Comment: @techfoobar: You're welcome... but I'll do even better: *[Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)* When coercion on non-matching types begins on point `2.`

Comment: @squint - Phew! All this while i never thought *such a thing* would be under the hood of the simple `==` - Thanks for the link.

Comment: thansk for your answers so far, see my edit. Might be related to the way ExtJs evaluates the config options

Comment: @DavidDierick: Saw your edit. In JavaScript, there is no difference between those two. http://jsfiddle.net/tQzkG/ In both cases, the config option will get the same value. Only way they would be different would be if the result of `.hasAccessTo()` is different.

Comment: @techfoobar: Yeah, it's a pretty crazy little operator.

Comment: squint is right, there's no difference between the two lines in your edit if your function is always returning a boolean. Could you give us the code of it?

Comment: Dear all, thanks for the help, 
the hasAccessTo will always return a boolean, that's one thing sure.

But ... erm ... the error came from a lack of parenthesis in a compound condition of the view button,
the correct version being :

`hidden: ( !(Myuser.hasAccessTo('ViewAuthorisationPanel')) || Myuser.hasAccessTo('EditAuthorisationPanel') )`

Weirdly enough, this was affecting the visibility of the other toolbar buttons with correct expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are mostly right

```
!(true) is false
!(false) is true
```

and

```
 true == false is false
 false == false is true
```

So if the input is only true and false but if the input is a empty array
then you could have

```
 ![] is false
```

but

```
  []==false is true
```